# Paths not hyperlinking correctly

Tags: grep, rgrep, compile-mode

Recently when running compile, the error messages don't get hyperlinked properly.  I get this type of error message:

```
../build/obj/DerivedClass.cpp:45:18: error: expected type-specifier
```

The buffer hyperlinks only part of the path:

```
ss.cpp:10148:18
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

EDIT:

I get the same problem when performing rgrep or grep.

EDIT 2:

Following [Drew's](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/105/drew) comment.  I ran `emacs -Q`.  The paths hyperlinked correctly.  I then loaded the init file, `load-file`, expecting the paths to be hyperlinked incorrecty.  However, they remained correct. Restarting emacs with no options had broken hyperlinks.

I then ran `emacs --no-desktop` to try and isolate if the problem existed in the init file or the desktop file.  Paths were hyperlinked correctly.  So the problem must be in the desktop file. I did not want to lose my buffer states stored in the desktop file by performing `desktop-clear`.  Instead I performed `desktop-read`, saved the desktop, quit emacs, then started emacs without and optiong: `emacs`.  Paths are hyperlinked correctly.  The problem appears to be fixed.  I can restart emacs several times without seeing the problem.

My assumption is that something in the desktop file was causing the bug.  Hind sight tells me I should have saved a copy of the desktop file and then done a diff after fixing the problem to see what caused it.

Comment: Not enough info, probably. Maybe try to provide a recipe, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). Consider also filing a bug report, if you think that for your context `compile` is not doing the right thing: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in EDIT 2 of the question, the desktop file must have been corrupted.  It appears that fixing the desktop file fixed the problem.